# "OSError: [WinError 126] No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado" al importar vlc (python-vlc)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo un problema al intentar usar `python-vlc` para reproducir archivos de audio.

He instalado el paquete mediante:

> pip install python-vlc

Éste es el código que estoy probando:

```
import os.path
import sys
import vlc

p = vlc.MediaPlayer("international love.flac")
p.play()
```

El archivo de audio se encuentra en la misma carpeta que el script. Este es el error completo que obtengo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*python-vlc* es un binding basado en *ctypes* sobre *libvlc*. El error lo que muestra es que ctypes no encuentra la biblioteca *libvlc.dll*, la cual está por lo general en `C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\libvlc.dll` (64 bits) o `C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\libvlc.dll` (32 bits).

Tienes que tener instalado VLC, para poder usar python-vlc. Es imprescindible  tener en cuenta que si usas Python 64 bits necesitas tener la versión de 64 bits de VLC, si usas Python 32 bits debes tener la versión de 32 bits de VLC:

- [Versión 64 bits VLC para Windows.](https://get.videolan.org/vlc/3.0.2/win64/vlc-3.0.2-win64.exe)
- [Versión 32 bits VLC para Windows.](https://get.videolan.org/vlc/3.0.2/win32/vlc-3.0.2-win32.exe)

Si no estas seguro de si estas usando la versión de 64 o 32 bits de Python basta con que lances el intérprete interactivo en la terminal:

> C:\> py -3.6
>   Python 3.6.1 (v3.6.1:69c0db5, Mar 21 2017, 18:41:36) [MSC v.1900 **64 bit (AMD64)] on win32**
>   Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>   >>>

En tu caso por la traza parece ser que usas Python de 32 bits. Por lo tanto necesitarías la versión de 32 bits de VLC o instalar la [versión de 64 bits](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-365/) de Python.