# ¿Cómo hacer que mi ordenador hable con Python?

Tags: python

Intento que mi computadora hable con la funcionalidad de traducción de Google Translate en Ubuntu Utility Ubuntu16.04. Encontré una forma de hacerlo utilizando la biblioteca de voz `speak` y [este repositorio](https://github.com/MauryaRitesh/Speech-to-Text-and-Text-to-Speech), pero tengo un error con VLC y no he encontrado un error similar en Internet.

Probé esta pieza de código:

```
...
# for text to speech
import webbrowser as wb
import speak

# running music
from pygame import mixer
... 

class ActionTranslate(Action):
    def name(self):
        return 'action_translate'

    def run (self,dispatcher,tracker,domain):

        try:
            # What Google thinks you said
            text = tracker.get_slot('sentenceToTranslate')
            if tracker.get_slot('voice') is 'en':
                lang = 'en' 
            else:
                lang = 'ko'

            # Google saying what he thinks you said
            speak.speak(text, lang)

            f_text = 'https://www.google.co.in/search?q=' + text
            wb.get(chrome_path).open(f_text)

        except Exception as e:
            print (e)
```

Y me contestaba el terminal que no hay `vlc binaryy` :

```
RuntimeError: vlc binary could not be found
```

No pienso que `vlc binary`  es una biblioteca que puede ser instalada.

Ya habia intentado instalar vlc binary:

```
    (MoodBotEnv) mike@mike-thinks:~/Programing/Rasa/moodbot$ pip install vlc binary
    Collecting vlc
      Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/97/e1/c593ef67290beb7443a66745d61b7a99de13fe1de5ed2c8afd9d430b0545/vlc-0.0.0.tar.gz
    Collecting binary
      Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b4/ba/37de520e4870635793164a3d6861d98357d4e43aa6ce244327183ccaa3cb/binary-1.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    Building wheels for collected packages: vlc
      Running setup.py bdist_wheel for vlc ... done
      Stored in directory: /home/mike/.cache/pip/wheels/d8/76/c9/1a45d351726de88b1e7718560862cea8e46dc022b6cf1bdeba
    Successfully built vlc
    tensorboard 1.8.0 has requirement bleach==1.5.0, but you'll have bleach 2.1.3 which is incompatible.
    bleach 2.1.3 has requirement html5lib!=1.0b1,!=1.0b2,!=1.0b3,!=1.0b4,!=1.0b5,!=1.0b6,!=1.0b7,!=1.0b8,>=0.99999999pre, but you'll have html5lib 0.9999999 which is incompatible.
    slackclient 1.2.1 has requirement requests<3.0a0,>=2.11, but you'll have requests 2.5.3 which is incompatible.
    Installing collected packages: vlc, binary
    Successfully installed binary-1.0.0 vlc-0.0.0
```

Pero se queda el error:

```
(MoodBotEnv) mike@mike-thinks:~/Programing/Rasa/moodbot$ python train_online.py INFO:rasa_nlu.components:Added 'nlp_spacy' to component cache. Key 'nlp_spacy-en'.
/home/mike/Programing/Rasa/moodbot/MoodBotEnv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rasa_nlu/extractors/entity_synonyms.py:85: UserWarning: Failed to load synonyms file from './models/nlu/default/moodnlu/entity_synonyms.json'
  "".format(entity_synonyms_file))
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train_online.py", line 38, in <module>
    run_weather_online(ConsoleInputChannel(), nlu_interpreter)
  File "train_online.py", line 23, in run_weather_online
    interpreter=interpreter)
  File "/home/mike/Programing/Rasa/moodbot/MoodBotEnv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rasa_core/agent.py", line 42, in __init__
    self.domain = self._create_domain(domain)
  File "/home/mike/Programing/Rasa/moodbot/MoodBotEnv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rasa_core/agent.py", line 235, in _create_domain
    return TemplateDomain.load(domain)
  File "/home/mike/Programing/Rasa/moodbot/MoodBotEnv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rasa_core/domain.py", line 446, in load
    **additional_arguments
  File "/home/mike/Programing/Rasa/moodbot/MoodBotEnv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rasa_core/domain.py", line 518, in __init__
    action_factory, action_classes, action_names, templates)
  File "/home/mike/Programing/Rasa/moodbot/MoodBotEnv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rasa_core/domain.py", line 525, in instantiate_actions
    custom_actions = action_factory(action_classes, action_names, templates)
  File "/home/mike/Programing/Rasa/moodbot/MoodBotEnv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rasa_core/actions/factories.py", line 77, in local_action_factory
    actions.append(_action_class(name))
  File "/home/mike/Programing/Rasa/moodbot/MoodBotEnv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rasa_core/actions/factories.py", line 48, in _action_class
    cls = utils.class_from_module_path(action_name)
  File "/home/mike/Programing/Rasa/moodbot/MoodBotEnv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rasa_core/utils.py", line 53, in class_from_module_path
    m = importlib.import_module(module_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/mike/Programing/Rasa/moodbot/actions.py", line 13, in <module>
    import speak
  File "/home/mike/Programing/Rasa/moodbot/MoodBotEnv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/speak/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    raise RuntimeError("vlc binary could not be found")
RuntimeError: vlc binary could not be found
```

#### Actualizacion :

Creo que la instalación de VLC con el enlace dado por FJSévilla resuelve el error. Sin embargo, ahora tengo estos errores. Me pregunto si esto es porque Ubuntu 16.04 no es compatible con VLC Media Player para Ubuntu

```
    INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): api.voicerss.org
could not locate runnable browser

    [00007fe7a8c0c2b8] es demux error: cannot peek
    [00007fe7a8c0c2b8] es demux error: cannot peek
    [mp3 @ 0x7fe7a8c5d860] Header missing
```

Comment: Pareciera ser que lo que te falta es instalar el `vlc` o al menos no se lo encuentra en la ejecución del script-

Comment: @PatricioMoracho hmm, Ya traté de instalarlo por si acaso.

Comment: Marine1 si estamos hablando de libvlc tienes que instalar el reproductor vlc (además de instalar el binding python-vlc vía pip) y este tiene que ser de 64 bits si usas python 64 bits y de 32 bits si tu intérprete es de 32 bits: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/163906/oserror-winerror-126-no-se-puede-encontrar-el-m%c3%b3dulo-especificado-al-import/163919#163919

Comment: Si con nativo te refieres a instalarlo mediante los repositorios del SO si, https://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-ubuntu.html. No obstante estoy presuponiendo que con "vlc binary" se refiere al reproductor VLC y que usa `libVLC.so` para reproducir el audio... Desconozco el paquete `speak` que causa el error, si sigues con problemas muestra el origen del paquete o el contenido de ".../site-packages/speak/__init__.py" a ver si es de ayuda. Por cierto [vlc](https://pypi.org/project/vlc/#files) en PYPI es un paquete vacío (solo han reservado el nombre).

Comment: podrias revisar esto: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J_aOAI218gw

Comment: @FJSevilla Ja, parece que no es compatible con la versión 16.04 de Ubuntu. Pero no sé si está relacionado con el error: `es demux error: cannot peek`y `Header missing`

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar la librería **pyttsx3**. Utiliza las funcionalidades de windows para transformar texto escrito en voz. Mira el siguiente ejemplo:

```
import pyttsx3
engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
engine.say('hello, how are you?')
engine.runAndWait()
```